# listing files in use or methods etc being called

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm getting this error all of a sudden - obviously I've changed something but I can't figure out what. I've checked all files for any whitespace before/after the `<?php ?>` tags but they're all fine.

`Warning (2): session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/dev/public_html/app/Controller/PostsController.php:1) [APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 2]`

I'm basically using cakephp and hybridauth and it requires you to put `session_start()` at the beginning of your AppController.php file, which was working fine until recently. On some pages it still works ok without causing any errors, but on others like the homepage I get this error occur now.

Is there any way I can find out what models/controllers/views are being used at this point to determine the difference between the pages when it is and isn't working?

Comment: Have you checked for [byte order marks](https://www.google.com/search?q=BOM%20headers%20already%20sent&hl=en)?

Comment: hmm good call, I'll have a look that all files are in UTF-8 mode...

Comment: I converted every file to "UTF8 without BOM" and it seems to have fixed it all :) hurray! Thanks @ndm